# SQL - Count of instances between two dates for mutliple criteria

Tags: sql, count

I have a table of account numbers with a date range. I must use another table of data to determine how many times we interacted with that account between the date range. I'm at a loss where to even start.

Table1

```
+------+------------+------------+  
| Acct |  EndDate   | StartDate  |  
+------+------------+------------+  
|    1 | 2017-02-14 | 2016-12-16 |  
|    2 | 2017-02-14 | 2016-12-16 |  
|    3 | 2017-02-13 | 2016-12-15 |  
+------+------------+------------+
```

Table2

```
+------+--------------+
| acct | calllog_date |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | 2016-06-16   |
|    1 | 2016-08-15   |
|    1 | 2015-11-10   |
|    2 | 2015-11-10   |
|    2 | 2015-11-13   |
|    2 | 2015-11-16   |
|    2 | 2015-11-19   |
|    3 | 2015-11-19   |
|    3 | 2015-11-23   |
|    4 | 2015-11-30   |
+------+--------------+
```

Comment: what is your dbms? what should the output look like? what have you already tried?

Comment: An idea to start...query the 2nd table where the callog_date is between your EndDate and StartDate from the 1st table for the same Acct

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `JOIN` based on a match between the date values:

```
SELECT t1.Acct, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 
   ON t1.Acct = t2.Acct AND t2.calllog_date BETWEEN t1.StartDate AND t1.EndDate
GROUP BY t1.Acct
```